# Custom made ros package in a running docker image/container [UAV control]

Tags: c++, docker, package, ros, px4

I'm a novice in ROS and especially docker as I discovered it during this job assignment that I'm working on.
They sent me a docker image with everything that I need on it (PX4-Autopilot,MAVROS, Gazebo for simulation and QGroundControl)

I have to create a ROS node to achieve a mission (on an IRIS UAV) so I created a new package and when I tried to run/compile it, rospack couldn't find it.

I followed all the steps from ROS Wiki and when I ran the catkin_make there weren't any errors or issues but the package is nowhere to be found for ROS.

When I searched I noticed a small difference between my compilation and the one that I was supposed to get (and yes I tried to source the path again)

```
root@Kyo-PC:~/tii_ws# catkin_create_pkg tii_pkg std_msgs rospy roscpp rospack mavros
Created file tii_pkg/package.xml
Created file tii_pkg/CMakeLists.txt
Created folder tii_pkg/include/tii_pkg
Created folder tii_pkg/src
Successfully created files in /root/tii_ws/tii_pkg. Please adjust the values in package.xml.

root@Kyo-PC:~/tii_ws# catkin_make
Base path: /root/tii_ws
Source space: /root/tii_ws/src
Build space: /root/tii_ws/build
Devel space: /root/tii_ws/devel
Install space: /root/tii_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/root/tii_ws/build"
####
####
#### Running command: "make -j8 -l8" in "/root/tii_ws/build"
####
```

The difference is at the end as I should have had `"make -j4 -l4"`

Does anyone know how can I make this work and be able to use my own scripts with PX4 ?
Thank you.

Comment: Can you upload somewhere your newly created package? Is your package empty?
This difference depends on your CPU. It is about how many cores are used for compilation.

Comment: The package isn't empty but I found where was the issue, I didn't notice that it was created in /tii_ws/  instead of tii_ws/src